# Append rows to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am really struggling to make it work...
How can I get a Series, transform it to a dataframe, add a column to it, and concatenate it in a loop?

The pseudo code is below, but the correct syntax is a mystery to me:

The Pseudo code is:

```
def func_B_Column(df):
    return 1

df_1 = (...) # columns=['a', 'etc1', 'etc2']
df_2 = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])

listOfColumnC = ['c1','c2','c3']

for var in listOfColumnC :
    series = df_1.groupby('a').apply(func_B_Column) #series object should have now 'a' as index, and func_B_Column as value
    aux = series.to_frame('b')
    aux['c'] = aux.apply(lambda x: var, axis=1) #add another column 'c' to the series object

    df_2 = df_2 .append(aux) #concatenate the results as rows, at the end
```

Comment: You can't add a column to a Series. Only DataFrames consists of columns.

Comment: indeed....   i will edit the post

Comment: And how the series must be concatenated? As a column or as rows? If as rows, what column will receive values?

Comment: Should be concatenated as rows, at the end.
Column A = index,
Column B = value,
Column C = Loop Variable

Answer (score 0):

Edited after the question's refinement

```
  df_2 = DataFrame()  
  for var in listOfColumnC :
    df_2 = df_2.append(DataFrame({'b': df_1.groupby('a').apply(func_B_Column), 'c': var}))
```